# Inserting data into database with autonumber in VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I'm trying to insert data into a database with an autonumber in MS Access as primary key. I get an error saying "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. The data types in MS Access are Autonumber (I didn't include it in the INSERT statement), String (@OrderNo), String (@Product), Number (@Qty), and Date (@TDate). Here's the image: [image]

Here's my code:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Daily Inventory.accdb;"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Table1 Values(@OrderNo, @Product, @Qty, @TDate)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", TxtOrder.Text.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", row.Cells("Product").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", row.Cells("Qty").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDate", Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Close()
                End If

                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

Comment: In your INSERT query, specify the Columns you're updating (e.g., `INSERT INTO Table1 ([sequence of Columns]) VALUES ([sequence of corresponding values])`) and use `Parameters.Add()` instead of `AddWithValue()`, specifying the Columns' data type explicitly.

Comment: [OLEDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) doesn't use named parameters, but you can use them in when you add parameters to help with debugging. You have your instance of `OleDbConnection` in a "using statement". It's unclear why you would close it. Try the following: `New OleDbCommand("Insert into Table1 (OrderNo, Product, Qty, Price, TDate ) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)` where `OrderNo`, `Product`, `Qty`, `Price`, `TDate` are the names of your database columns. If named parameters are used, the parameter names will be ignored.

Comment: Always keep in mind that, with OleDb, the names assigned to Parameters don't matter, only the order in which you add them matters. It must match the order of Columns in the query.

Comment: @Jimi I tried doing the `Parameters.Add()` but I still encountered an error. I'm not really sure how to do it since I just started learning about databases.

Comment: @user9938 Not correct, you can specify names (as in `@SomeName`, or whatever else), but the names are simply ignored (as described in my previous comment). So, you can specify a Parameter *name* and something else entirely in the query. It doesn't matter. The `?` symbol just enforces the concept, but it's use is not a requirement.

Comment: @Jimi: Perhaps I was misunderstood. The names are ignored in the SQL statement (ie: `INSERT INTO ...`). However, the names, if provided, can be stored within the `Parameters.Add` (or `Parameters.AddWithValue) statement which can be useful for debugging.

Comment: @user9938 I did this: `
New OleDbCommand("Insert into Table1 (OrderNo, Product, Qty, Price, TDate) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)` Now, the error said "Parameter ?_2 has no default value"

Comment: If you have tried some other code, then post that code, too. Add it to the question (don't replace the existing). You need to be sure what the data type of your Column is. See [Microsoft Access Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15). It may also be useful: [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words)

Comment: @user9938 Yes, but you can use *names* in the query, too, not just the Parameters. The only important thing to remember is that Parameters are positional here, not named and the names assigned are ignored (this includes `?`).

Comment: @Jimi The data types I have in MS Access are autonumber, string, string, number, and date.

Comment: You don't need to tell me, you have to update your question. Post any information that can help people generate an answer that makes sense in your context.

Comment: @Jimi: Yes. We're in agreement. However, I don't use them in the SQL statement when using OLEDB so that I don't forget that OLEDB doesn't use named parameters.

Comment: You don't provide a value for the `AutoNumber` column, which is why it's necessary to list the column names in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @user9938 I did not include the autonumer column in the insert statement.

Comment: Please add an image that shows your database column definitions. (ie: Design View).

Comment: @user9938 All right, it's just that what you posted earlier seems to suggest that using the `?` symbol is a requirement. I appreciate the note about the Connection, though :) (it's a typical thing you see in code copied a piece here, one there and some school projects). -- Post the answer, the OP seems eager to have one (the correct Data Types used in the database is actually a requirement).

Comment: @user9938 I have edited it

Comment: Your database design seems off. Please see [Description of the database normalization basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description) (or search for `database normalization`). Also, since you seem to be using a `DataGridView`, you may consider binding the DataGridView's `DataSource` to a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0) instead or programmatically adding rows to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your sql to "Insert into Table1 (OrderNo,Product,Qty,TDate) Values(@OrderNo, @Product, @Qty, @TDate)".

The following code works for me.

```
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=...;"
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Table1 (OrderNo,Product,Qty,TDate) Values(@OrderNo, @Product, @Qty, @TDate)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", TxtOrder.Text.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", row.Cells("Product").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", row.Cells("Qty").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDate", Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Close()
                End If

                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this and it did insert in the database but at the same time, it gave me an error saying "Parameter @Product has no default value."

Comment: Hello again. I resolved the issue. Turns out I didn't set the AllowUserToAddRows to false. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we dealing with a bit of a chicken and a egg problem here?

I mean, how did the grid get created?

How and where did you setup the columns in the grid?

lets drop a data grid view into a form. Drop in a button.

We have this code to load up the grid:

```
Private Sub HotelGridEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    LoadGrid()

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active FROM tblHotelsA 
            ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData

        End Using
    End Using


End Sub
```

So, now we have this:

[image]

Now, in a above, I can cursor around - make any edits I want.

I can also type in on the bottom blank row to add new rows.

I can click on the left side recordselector, and hit delete key.

Now, to save my edits, save my addtitions, and save my deletes?

I have the one button at the top, and this code works to do all updates, all addtitions, and all deletes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' save all edits, and new rows, and deletes
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active FROM tblHotelsA"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daC As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(DataGridView1.DataSource)

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

So, not a lot of code.

In fact, often using a data table is a lot less work, since you don't have to mess with all those parameters anyway - even if your data grid was somehow not feed from the database. But, if you feeding the "grid" from the database, then really, you can just add rows - and then write some code to send the changes back to the database with the above code. And if you want to start out with a blank grid - not show previous rows, then just add to your sql like this:

```
SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = 0 Order by Hotelname
```

Use above to create a data table without any rows but STILL bind that to the grid, and thus once again, to add, or delete rows, you just edit and add them, and again the SAME code I had above will work to save edits, deletes and additions.